# How can we write (2,5) in the countable family of disjoint open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I have just read a theorem which states that "Every open subset of R is the union of countable family of disjoint open intervals".
Now,I want know how can we write (2,5) in the countable family of disjoint open intervals?
I attempted to pursue this as 
$$ \bbox[border:2px solid red]
{
(2,5)=(2,3)\cup(3,4)\cup(4,5)
}
$$
but it makes exclude {3,4} from (2,5).
I know only elementary metric space,so please explain this in detail with autoritative statements and if possible with some sort of visualizing procedure.
Thank You!!

Comment: $(2, 5)$ is itself an open interval...

Comment: Expanding on @Travis point, finite union is also countable, so you can just express $(2, 5)$ as a countable union of a single interval, that is, itself.

In fact, it can be proven that $(2, 5)$ cannot be written as a union of more than one disjoint open interval -- that what the whole notion of connectedness is all about.

Comment: can you please give me an example of some subset of R that can be written as the union of countable family of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: @PKStyles $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$ for example.

Comment: But (2,5) is also an open subset of R?Why it would not agree with the theorem?

Comment: Either the book defined somewhere that "countable means either finite or countably infinite," or if it didn't, then the author was simply negligent in the use of language. The theorem should read "the union of a finite or countable family of..." or "the union of an at most countable family of."

Comment: The theorem does not say "countably infinite", it says "countable". This includes "finite" and "one". Since $\{(2,5)\}$ is a set containing one set, it is finite, hence countable.

Comment: @Bungo - formally, countable does mean infinite. Sometimes for language simplification people use the convention that "countable" will mean "at most countable" but it is best if this convention is made explicit.

Comment: @Bungo I disagree with the statement "formally, countable does mean infinite." It depends which text you're using. Plenty of texts *formally* define a set to be countable iff it is in bijection with *a subset of* the natural numbers. (For instance, the books I learned from did.) There really *are* differing conventions on this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I disagree with the same statement. Your disagreement is not with me. :-)

Comment: @Bungo Whoops, my bad! I'm *good* at reading comprehension! :P

Answer (score 2):

At heart, this question depends entirely on what "countable" means.

Here are two options:

- A set $A$ is said to be *countable* if there is a one-to-one function from $A$ into the set of natural numbers.
- A set $A$ is said to be *countable* if there is a one-to-one function from $A$ into **and onto** the set of natural numbers.

As far as I'm aware, all textbooks use a definition that is equivalent to one of the above options. If (one equivalent to) the former option is your definition of countable, then any set satisfying the latter option is countable **and infinite**. If (one equivalent to) the latter option is your definition of countable, then any set satisfying the former option is **either** countable **or finite**.

If (one equivalent to) the former option is your definition of countable, then $(2,5)$ ***is*** the union of a countable set of pairwise disjoint open intervals, namely: $$(2,5)=\bigcup\bigl\{(2,5)\bigr\}.$$

If (one equivalent to) the latter option is your definition of countable, then you are sadly out of luck.

> **Claim**: Given real numbers $a,b$ with $a<b,$ the open interval $(a,b)$ cannot be obtained as the union of a(n infinite) countable set of pairwise disjoint, non-trivial open intervals.
>
> **Proof**: Let $\mathcal I$ be any (infinite) countable family of pairwise disjoint, non-trivial open subintervals of $(a,b),$ and fix any $I\in\mathcal I.$ Without loss of generality, we may assume that $I=(u,v),$ where $u,v\in (a,b].$ Since $I$ is non-trivial, then we also have $u<v.$
>
> Let $J$ be any open interval such that $u\in J.$ That is, $J=(w,x),$ where $w$ and $x$ are real numbers such that $w<u<x.$ Put $y=\min\{v,x\}.$ Since $u<v$ and $u<x,$ then $u<y,$ and so $(u,y)$ is non-empty. Readily, $(u,y)=I\cap J.$ Hence, given any open interval containing $u$ as an element, we have that $I$ and $J$ are not disjoint. Since $I$ is disjoint from all other elements of $\mathcal I,$ it follows that $u$ is not an element of any elements of $\mathcal I.$ However, $u$ ***is*** an element of $I,$ so $I\nsubseteq\bigcup\mathcal I,$ and so $I\neq\bigcup\mathcal I.$

I suspect that your text has defined "countable" by (a way equivalent to) the first option I gave above, but that you've previously encountered a text that defined "countable" by (a way equivalent to) the latter option I gave above. If so, your confusion is perfectly natural!